# How to set Firefox's new tab page as the home page?

Tags: firefox

I like the brand new "new tab page" in Firefox 13 which displays clickable screenshots of the most visited web pages, but I would like to have it also as home page (as the good plugin new tab jumpstart permits in his implementation of this same feature).

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the URL for home page in Preferences to `about:newtab`. If you want to access the home page afterwards, you can try the URL `about:home`.